# "Bricks Game" from HackerRank

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've been trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101apr14/challenges/play-game) problem from HackerRank's Dynamic Programming section. I read the editorial solution and understand it. However, it jumps straight to dynamic programming approach. I want to know what would the brute force approach be for this problem.

> **Description:** You and your friend decide to play a game using a stack consisting of N bricks. In this game, you can alternatively remove 1, 2 or 3 bricks from the top, and the numbers etched on the removed bricks are added to your score. You have to play so that you obtain the maximum possible score. It is given that your friend will also play optimally and you make the first move.

My initial thought is to enumerate all possible 1,2,3-length combinations combinations of bricks, starting from the top of stack down to the bottom. Let's call this enumeration S. Then, find all possible (x,y) for all x (your score) and y (opponent's score) in S, where x != y. Finally iterate, through all such pairs and compute your maximum score (e.g. max sum of x's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here dynamic programming is just a method to avoid computing the same subproblems many times (other possibility is to use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).

The general idea to approach these kind of problems is the following:

Let `A` and `B` be the players and `A` moves first. Moreover, let `f(n,p)` denote the maximum score for player `p` with stack of size `n`, i.e. it is `p`'s turn on stack of size `n`.

The idea is very simple, `A` wants to maximize `f(n,A)`. Notice that `A` from initial position given in the input can make at most 3 different moves:

- take 1 brick
- take 2 bricks
- take 3 bricks

Moreover, if `A` scores `X`, then `B` scores `S(n) - X`, where `S(n)` is the sum of scores of `n` bottom bricks.

Based on these observations, we can write that:

`f(n,A) = max(S(n)-f(n-1,B), S(n)-f(n-2,B), S(n)-f(n-3,B))`.

In other words, his best result is maximum from these available moves (notice that if stack is small, less than 3 moves may be available).

Now, dynamic programming is just used to avoid computing the same values of `f(n,p)` many times - if you expand the formula for `f(n,A)`, you will find out that they can occur there more and more when `n` grows. So in order to optimize the solution, already computed values of `f` are stored in the memory and returned in constant time when needed.

Comment: But we don't want the maximum score for intermediate states. Instead, we want to have the final maximum score. For example, consider arr = [0,1,2,1,999], the solution should be score(A) = 999 and score(B) = 4 as the player A should take the first and the final bricks. Then for every i from 1 to 4, the score of A is smaller than the score of B.

Comment: @lenhhoxung the solution I gave maximizes the final score, take a look at the formula and the definition for `f(n,A)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to DP so not sure I understand it well. Here you defined "let f(n,p) denote the maximum score for player p with stack of size n". Then a player should have the maximum score for every step (i.e., n changes)? Or maybe I'm confused?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax). Where you generally build a complete tree where one level will generate all possible moves by you and next level will generate all possible moves for your opponent for every states generated by you on previous level and go on. In each level, you have to minimize the possible loss for worst-case scenario of next level. Here all possible moves/branch are generated so its pretty much brute-force.

Obviously you can apply pruning on Minimax tree but you should look at the brute force method first.